# CMD FINDSTR execution issue

Tags: cmd, findstr

I am currently trying to execute a search (specific string in specific files) in a server by using CMD and command FINDSTR as follows (calling this .bat file from CMD):

```
@echo off

>C:\Users\myuser\test1.txt (
     pushd \\Targeted_Server\DATA\
     FINDSTR /S "XXX=XXXXXX" *."sas"
     popd
if not errorlevel 0 goto ERR
)
```

Problem: the script does not end (keeping a blank space in CMD) and the results file is kept empty (tried 2ish hours and still no results). Do you guys know any chance of getting it done quicker or most important: **how to get the results file written as results are being found by the script (real time)?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: __FINDSTR__ command line is wrong. Run in a command prompt window `findstr /?` for help on this command. Try in your batch file`%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /S /C:"XXX=XXXXXX" "*.sas" >C:\Users\myuser\test1.txt`. And yes, use in batch file full qualified name of executable and redirect just output of __FINDSTR__ to the file, except you want also output of the other commands in the file `test1.txt`. BTW: Testing a batch file is done by running it from within a cmd prompt window and not by double clicking on it to see also perhaps output error messages. `@echo off` should be removed too.

Comment: Well, a recursive search in all `*.sas` files can of course take a long time. I suggest to test your batch file first on a local directory with just 3 *.sas files on which one does not contain the searched string, another one contains the searched string one times and third one contains the searched string multiple times. And each SAS file should be in a different subdirectory of local directory. We can't help more without knowing directory structure, contents of files, expected output and of course the access permissions on server share.

Comment: @JoseM - Your previous comment looks like code. Please edit the question and add the code to it. It is difficult, almost impossible, to understand code in a comment.

Comment: @Mofi, what would be great is that the script writes the results as soon as it identifies the target string, as it would do in the CMD screen (which it does): **Script:**
`Y:\>C:\WINDOWS\System32\findstr.exe /L /S /C:"XXX=XXXXXXX" "*.sas"` **Results shown in CMD screen:** 
`Aal\Aal0230\0230 - Análisis PAS 2013\CODE\TARGET_2_PAS_2013.sas:libname dataga XXX=XXXXXXXXX =DATA; 
Aal\Aal0230\0230 - Análisis PAS 2013\CODE\TARGET_PAS_2013.sas:libname dataga XXX=XXXXXXXXXXXX;`.

Comment: Output redirection works in that manner whereby Windows file caching system is also active. So you have to refresh the Windows Explorer window with key F5 to see the results file growing in size while lines are written to the file. But what do you expect at all? The output file can't be viewed with most applications while the lines are written into the file. You can view the output file while it is written only with applications which do not try to open the file with a read/write lock like Total Commander.

Comment: BTW: Do you still redirect the output to __STDOUT__ of entire command block into the file or just of command __FINDSTR__ as I recommended in my first comment? What do you expect with `if not errorlevel 0 goto ERR` which means if exit code of previous command is __lower than__ `0` which is for your commands never true? `if errorlevel 1` means if exit code is __greater or equal__ `1` which looks like being what you really wanted here. This is explained on first help page of command __IF__ output on running `if /?` in a command prompt window.